# AWS MongoDB EC2 instance as localhost with EC2 application instance

Tags: mongodb, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, localhost

I'm actually new on AWS. And I configured 2 EC2 instances.

One for my MongoDB database and an other one for my application.

I'm using pymongo to make the connection. But If send data through instances each time, it takes too much time. I would like to know if it's possible to have the mongoDB instance as localhost for the application one, using groups or I don't know, to get better performances.

Or If it is better to put the database on the same instance as my application and get more EBS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be sure you know where your performance bottleneck is.

If both instances are in the same Availability Zone, network latency should not be the largest performance issue.  In fact if you have instances that are at least *large*... due to the better NIC... network latency should be a non-issue.

To know for sure, measure your network utilization with a monitoring tool.

If any of your working set (MongoDB documents that are used with any frequency) cannot fit in RAM of the instance, that means you are touching EBS.  EBS is *very, very slow* compared to what MongoDB needs.  I measured a single EBS volume using [iozone](http://iozone.org/) recently and found the EBS volume to be half as fast as my laptop's rotational hard drive.

You can improve EBS performance substantially by [striping multiple EBS volumes](http://dodizzle.com/setting-up-software-raid-zero-over-8-volumes) into a software RAID configuration.

The bottom line when running MongoDB on AWS is that you need enough RAM to hold the MongoDB documents that you will touch with any frequency.

Comment: I'll try to stripe multiple EBS and see the difference, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have an application in production that uses a mongodb instance on the same machine as the web server. Works fine for me but then I don't have need for scalability right now. One instance is enough.

So to answer your question, sure you can run it as localhost.

But if your app picks up and you need multiple instances or sharding or such then you'd have to have instances deployed on other machines as well.

Comment: I would not really advocate running on `localhost` unless you're really darn sure that the instance will not start swapping.  FourSquare went down when their MongoDB working set stopped fitting in RAM, and running things other than MongoDB on an instance just means there is less memory available to MongoDB.  http://blog.foursquare.com/2010/10/05/so-that-was-a-bummer/

Comment: What do you mean the instance could start swapping? Wouldn't that (swapping) also happen to a standalone EC2 instance on which one is hosting MongoDB?

Comment: Sure, but if you're also running Apache and other things on the one box, you will start swapping that much earlier.  MongoDB is really, really RAM hungry.

Comment: Oh you are talking about memory swapping. For some reason I thought you were talking about EC2 changing your physical machine from underneath you.